# Accessing json objects with no name

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, getjson

I'm struggling to access this json code below. Every json value I've previously seen is something like this:

```
 var hold = { name: 'alex', job: 'realtor'}
```

So to access the name I would do something like hold.name. But my json data looks like this

```
[
[
        {
            "count": "80",
            "countTxt":"Buyer logins",
            "participantsTxt":"Total for all participating member companies:",
            "participantCount":"523"
        },
        {
            "count": "233",
            "countTxt":"Searches",
            "participantsTxt":"Total for all participating member companies:",
            "participantCount":"628"
        },
        {
            "count": "533",
            "countTxt":"Views of our member pages",
            "participantsTxt":"Total for all participating member companies:",
            "participantCount":"2,365"
        }
    ],


[
        {
            "count": "80",
            "countTxt":"Total vists",
            "participantsTxt":"Total for all participating member companies:",
            "participantCount":"412"
        },
        {
            "count": "53",
            "countTxt":"Unique visitors",
            "participantsTxt":"Total for all participating member companies:",
            "participantCount":"731"
        },
        {
            "count": "1:12 min",
            "countTxt":"Total time spent on page",
            "participantsTxt":"Total for all participating member companies:",
            "participantCount":"784.2 mins"
        }
    ]
```

]

The data is nested and it has no name so I don't know how to access. I know the question seems somewhat rudimental but I haven't seen any examples parse code that looks like this. It's always a more simple example like the one above. My .getjson code looks like this ...

```
var requestURL = 'assets/js/stats.json';
$.getJSON(requestURL, function(data){
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            $('body').append($('<div>' + data[0].name, {

            }));
            console.log(data);
        });

    });
```

My console is returning two objects that look like this

```
Array[3], Array[3]] Array[3]: 
Array[3] [Array[3], Array[3]]
```

So I know it's getting data back I just need to be able to pick what I want a append it to the DOM. I've tried ten different variations but nothing works. Please help!?

Comment: just use [0] to access the first array etc. Or loop through them first and access them with index

Comment: just use [0] doesn't work. Also this is valid json checked at http://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to iterate one more time inside first iteration. You have one array that holds array of objects. So try something like this

http://jsfiddle.net/mnth1xe1/5/

```
$.each(data, function(key, val) {
    $.each(val, function(key, value) {

        console.log(value.countTxt);
    });

});
```

Comment: That didn't work just gave me more arrays in my console.

Comment: Please check out updated answer. Your object is stored inside value object in second iteration.

Comment: Thanks that was a huge piece of it now I need to loop through it and apply each one to a different piece of my HTML. You wouldn't happen to have any experience with that would you?

Comment: What exactly do you need to do with HTML and data? can you be more specific please so i can help you.

Comment: Also I'm a bit confused why for the second each statement did you pass 'val' as opposed to 'key'? I'm not sure why that works

Comment: For example if we have array and we iterate through array using each method than key would be index numbers from 0 to array.length - 1. And val is actually array that we need to iterate again to get our object

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65192/discussion-between-london804-and-user2432612).